# Why was the raster background chosen as background for Web Applications?

Tags: discussion, design

The current background reminds of sitting in a classroom and being punished by mathematics formulas.

Why was this background chosen?

Do others like it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a temporary background, all beta sites will start with it. They're [trying to go with a "sketchy" look and feel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55529/will-all-stack-exchange-sites-look-the-same/55542#55542).

Comment: k, that explains it. i strongly vote for a different, not so sketchy look in the final "product" :)

Answer (score 4):

It is sketchy because *the site itself is sketchy* -- it will only continue to exist, if the site has focus and audience!

While it's pretty much a given that web apps will make it due to popularity, any given site has to ...

- reach private beta
- meet the criteria to exit private beta
- reach public beta
- meet the criteria to exit public beta

... so, there must be enough *good* questions and answers, a solid population of users, and a certain amount of traffic.

Comment: The site itself looks awesome!

Comment: I like the look very much (for what it is right now, not for the post-beta site).

Comment: "the site itself is sketchy" - hence the sketchy look. I like it!