# Is this the "settled" look-and-feel?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was the raster background chosen as background for webapps?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59/why-was-the-raster-background-chosen-as-background-for-webapps)

I love the "graph paper and stencil" look to webapps.stackexchange. Is this the look-and-feel the site will have when it leaves beta, or is it just because it *is* a beta site?

Update: Indeed, this was discussed on [meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55529/will-all-stack-exchange-sites-look-the-same/55542#55542).

Comment: +1 - I absolutely love the look and feel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just for beta sites. Which is a pity, because I like it too.

Comment: aww. <!-- 15 chars -->

Comment: I told Jin our designer to not make it look so cool because of exactly that.  He ignored me :)